# How to place images in footer region through page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, media

I would like to know how to place images in footer region through page.tpl.php. I know a block can be created and done so but i want to do so using page.tpl.php. Where should i write the code?

Comment: just add an image in the tpl with an img tag.

Comment: do i do that after the footer is rendered i.e., after:                                                    <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>

Comment: that depends on where you want to place the image. is it above below towards the right or left etc... it is completely under your control do what ever you like :-)

Comment: i have placed an image before that...and if i place the image before it..would not it be in a region above footer, say content.I want my footer to have those images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not going to use blocks how about going a level deeper into the actual footer region template...

```
region--footer.tpl.php
```

Comment: this seems a good suggestion...so i need to write a new file for that? How should i proceed...i think i should create a region--footer.tpl.php file in my templates folder...Inside it what should i do...Do i just simply write the img tag and so on...or are there other issues to take care of?

Comment: I created the file and placed the image in it using <img> tag but i do not see it on my screen

Comment: It is in your themes template folder and have you cleared caches?

Comment: yes..have done that...the image is not displaying there...however if i check through firebug i see the img tag and the source and clicking it takes me to the image...so its not an issue if the path is wrong...I have created a custom region above the footer and placed fb-like box there using the social media module...i hope that is not causing any problem

Comment: Must be something else going on there, probably a CSS issue, play about with the style rules with firebug.